# When i switch View In TabBarController the ScrollView Stop Scroll,How to Solve it?

Tags: ios

in Controller A: here the Code:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:5 animations:^{
    [self.awardScrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(self.awardScrollView.frame.size.width * 19, 0)];
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    isFinished = YES;
}];
```

i set 5s to finish the animation,but i switch controller to **B** with **TabBarController**,i found the animation is stop in Controller A.How can i let the **ScrollView** continue Scroll Background in Controller A even i Switch to **Controller B**?

Answer (score 1):

Core Animation won't animate a view that's not in the on-screen view hierarchy. When a view is removed from the on-screen view hierarchy, Core Animation removes all animations from the view.

You can add another animation when the view comes back on screen if you want.

Comment: thanks, i know about this! I think When the Animation is not finished i will add a clear-color View on the KeyWindow,  When the Animation is Finished, i remove it